# Where can I find an Ubuntu iso under 700mb to install from CD?

Tags: system-installation

I need an Ubuntu iso under 700mb to install on old  Win 98 with wireless connection.

I can't use USB; the device won't boot from it. I tried changing the BIOS. Made usb stick with rufus. I can see files on the stick but can't boot. USB never turns on until program starts to load and than it's too late. So I need to boot from CD.

Comment: Doesn't the Network Installer work? https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD It's just ~50 MB

Comment: If the computer is very old, it is a good idea to try Lubuntu (32bit alias i386), which is a community flavour of Ubuntu. Lubuntu has a much lighter desktop environment, which means that it works with less CPU horsepower and less RAM. Lubuntu's iso files are also too big for CD, but you can start with the Ubuntu `mini.iso` or Network Installer described by @PerlDuck, and install `lubuntu-desktop` during or after the installation.

Comment: An alternative is to create a **PLOP** boot CD and chainload a Lubuntu USB live drive. See [this link and links from it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#PLoP_Boot_Manager).

Comment: You might try a different USB stick,  esp. if you have not tried to boot this one.  I have found that some boot and some don't even with a full up blanking with ``dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd**``.  Another thought: disable UEFI in the BIOS.

Comment: mini does not have wireless connection

Answer (score 3):

[The Mini ISO (scroll down on the linked page for download links)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) was made for fitting on regular CDs and even some mini CDs.

Since the software package installers are removed from the install CD to make it so small, you'll need an Internet connection (WiFi or Ethernet) on the computer you're installing it on in order to download them. It'll download up to several GB, so try to use an unmetered connection.

It can handle any official Ubuntu flavor you want, eventually presenting you a menu with all the options.

One drawback is that it only supports a BIOS install, not a UEFI install, so set your machine to BIOS mode. If your machine only supports UEFI, sorry, you'll need to burn a DVD or a large-enough USB drive instead.

Comment: once again mini doesn't support wireless connection