# mini startup with wireless connection

Tags: startup, ubuntu-minimal

Will a mini start up able up wireless internet for downloads. no wired internet. Usb boot not working and need under 700mb for CD.

Comment: Please provide a more details about your matter.

Comment: Related (and by the same author): https://askubuntu.com/q/1025904/504066

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try the Netboot images of Ubuntu, they are under 700MB. You can find them here: "http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/xenial/". Those images just boot the computer then the selected software is downloaded from Internet.